# Want to reduce execution time of a query in SP in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a search button on my page. If I have not specified any search filter and click on search button then it should display all the postal codes.
Here for every id there are many postal codes vary from length 3 to 6.

I have written a stored procedure which is huge because having many conditions for different each criteria as well.

My problem is below snippet of whole stored procedure. While executing it's taking almost 60% of total execution time and due to this my application shows below error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Code:

```
declare @id int


set @id= 21
select distinct T.PostalCode from Table T

where SUBSTRING(T.PostalCode,0,7) IN

(select PostalCode from Ref_Table where

ID=@id and LEN(PostalCode)=6)

UNION ALL

select distinct T.PostalCode from Table T

where SUBSTRING(T.PostalCode,0,6) IN

(select PostalCode from Ref_Table where

ID=@id and LEN(PostalCode)=5)

UNION ALL

select distinct T.PostalCode from Table T

where SUBSTRING(T.PostalCode,0,5) IN

(select PostalCode from Ref_Table where

ID=@id and LEN(PostalCode)=4)
UNION ALL

select distinct T.PostalCode from Table T

where SUBSTRING(T.PostalCode,0,4) IN

(select PostalCode from Ref_Table where

ID=@id and LEN(PostalCode)=3)
```

I have tried all possible options from my end. Can any one suggest me some other workaround for this to reduce its execution time.

Thanks

Shivani

Comment: How many records in `Table`? By using those `LEN` functions it will not be able to use an index on `Table.PostalCode` (if it exists). The answer is usually to rewrite the code in a way that does not use functions. For example it may be possible to replace all of that code with something like `T.PostalCode LIKE Ref_Table.PostalCode + '%`

Comment: The other thing to do is use CTRL-L to get the execution plan and see if there any particular area that uses a lot.. Fir example a table scan using a large percentage implies and index can be created to help (and it will actually suggest it)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the show plan would reveal nothing but table scan union table scan union ... the len and substr kill it